# how to remove auto scroll in coin slider

Tags: jquery, css

I used coin slider in my web page. I need to stop the auto scroll. And previous and next shows only the mouse over. I need it displays not on mouse over. Please guide me.

Answer (score 2):

Use the css style `overflow:hidden` on the auto scroll div.

and on your prev/next links styles, use display:none;

e.g.

```
a.prev, a.next {
display:none;
}
```

The most I can think of without seeing the markup.

Looks like line 17 of coin-slider.css

```
.cs-prev, .cs-next {
background-color: black;
color: white;
padding: 0px 10px;
display: none; /* Added */
}
```

Comment: sorry for the confusion. Previous and Next button shows normally show not on mouse over. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Take away the .yourdiv part then and just target those links. Edited answer.

Comment: Both links are hidden on mouse over. Thanks

Comment: Can you mark my reply as answered? :} Thanks and glad you got it working!

Comment: Previous and Next button shows normally show not on mouse over.

Comment: That should still remove them, do you have an public URL I could look at?